# Como passar o contexto da aplicação para o Adapter lendo Json usando AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

```
private class GetEmpresas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

... 

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        //Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                empresasJson = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_EMPRESAS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < empresasJson.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = empresasJson.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NOME);
                    String cidade = c.getString(TAG_CIDADE);
                    String endereco = c.getString(TAG_ENDERECO);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NOME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_CIDADE, cidade);
                    contact.put(TAG_ENDERECO, endereco);

                                                    empresas = new ArrayList<Empresas>();

                    Empresas item = new Empresas(name,endereco, R.drawable.logo);

                    empresas.add(item);

                    adapter = new AdapterEmpresas(empresas, ?????);

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

     ....

}
```

**ERRO**

```
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at com.solutudo.activities.Main$GetEmpresas.doInBackground(Main.java:137)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at com.solutudo.activities.Main$GetEmpresas.doInBackground(Main.java:1)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     ... 4 more
```

## Pergunta:

Como passo o contexto do método da onde eu to para o *adapter* que recebe o contexto?

Antes de carregar o Json, eu tinha criado outra classe, e quando eu passava o *this* como parâmetro, funcionava corretamente. Agora nesse outro método não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu sugiro algumas alterações. Em primeiro lugar, o motivo:

As operações relativas a UI do Android não podem ser feitas no método doInBackground, pois ele não é executado na Main Thread. Operações de UI só podem ser realizadas na Main Thread. Assim, você deve executar as operações relativas a UI no método onPostExecute, pois ele é executado na Main Thread.

Sobre a passagem do Context, a sugestão do lucasb.aquino está correta.

Sobre o erro de NullPointerException, acredito que possar ser decorrente do ponto inapropriado de atualização da UI.

Dessa forma seu código ficaria assim

**O método onCreate**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new GetEmpresas(this).execute();
}
```

**Sua AsyncTask GetEmpresas**

```
private class GetEmpresas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Empresas>> {

    private Context mContext;

    public GetEmpresas(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Empresas> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ...

        return empresas;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Empresas> listEmpresas) {
        super.onPostExecute(listEmpresas);

        adapter = new AdapterEmpresas(listEmpresas, mContext);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Caso o NullPointerException persista, disponibilize mais do seu código para que seja possível uma melhor avaliação do problema.

Comment: Legal Francisco, obrigado pelas informações. Agora coloquei o preenchimento da lista no PostExecute e funcionou. Faltou também, eu ter iniciado o ListView com o findviewById, fiz tudo isso e tá funcionando agora. Valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um construtor que recebe o contexto.

Declare dentro da sua classe GetEmpresas a propriedade mContext como abaixo:

```
private Context mContext;
```

E depois crie um construtor passando o Context.

```
public GetEmpresas(Context ctx){
    mContext = ctx;
}
```

Agora no trecho da chamada que você passava this, passe a propriedade mContext.

```
adapter = new AdapterEmpresas(empresas, mContext);
```

Edit: na sua Activity...

```
GetEmpresas getEmpresasAsync = new GetEmpresas(this);
getEmpresasAsync.execute();
```

Comment: Cara, tudo isso dentro do meu getEmpresa? Eu to fazendo a chamada dele pelo OnCreate. Assim: new GetEmpresas().execute(); Ai dá erro se eu não passar nada, pq ele tenta passar para o construtor.

Comment: Então, na verdade, tá tudo dentro do getEmpresa. Ele extende do AsyncTask.

Comment: Sim, o único trecho fora seria sua chamada para a AsyncTask, onde você precisa instancia-la e ai você passa o context da sua Activity para o construtor criado.

Comment: Chamando dessa forma, você passará a chamar da seguinte: new GetEmpresas(this).execute(); Partindo do principio que você esteja realizando a chamada a partir de uma Activity.

Comment: Deu erro também... fiz como você disse, e o erro chega no memso momento ainda.

Comment: Poste o erro do Logcat, por favor.

Comment: 01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-30 18:21:25.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.fi

Comment: O log completo ajuda mais. A linha 299 seria essa adapter = new AdapterEmpresas(empresas, mContext)?

Comment: Não, não chega na linha 299. Postei na pergunta o erro.

Comment: Dando uma olhada na sua classe eu percebi que você está retornando null mas seu método doInBackground não retorna nada (void).

Tente debugar e verifique se o mContext passado para o adapter está nulo. Creio que não está e ai temos outro problema no código. O doInBackground está sendo executado integralmente, o problema pode estar onPostExecute().

Comment: Então, mas se eu tirar o return, dá erro. Também vi no logcat que dá erro na linha 137 que é essa: listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Verifique se o seu adapter está nulo. Se tirar o return qual erro acontece? Não faz sentido, o seu método é void, não espera retorno, teoricamente não deveria nem compilar. "Void methods cannot return a value".

Comment: Não, meu adapter não está null, esta com.nome.adapter.AdapterEmpresas@40e0ae30

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12762/discussion-between-artur-and-lucasb-aquino)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @lucasb.aquino o método como vc disse estava certo de passar o contexto, porém, precisaria ser no PostExecute. Obrigado!!